# Replace everything but the number outside the brackets?

Tags: c#, regex, regexp-replace

Input String:

```
string input="12,15,22,(46),78,234,1,89,12,(21,99,66),78,65,63,(343,5)";
```

Replace comma with dot but only applicable for outside the brackets.
Expected Output:

```
string ExpectedOutput="12.15.22.(46).78.234.1.89.12.(21,99,66).75.65.63.(343,5)";
```

I tired so far

```
\d*(\(\d*?\))\d*
```

but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Does this _need_ to be done with regex? This might be easier to do with string.Split.

Comment: Please let me know how to ignore comma inside the brackets?

Comment: You....didn't answer my question.

Comment: Does this need to be done with regex? - not required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
new Regex(@"(?<=\d|\))(?<!\([\d,]+),");
```

and replace with a dot (`.`).

**Explanation**:

`(?<=\d|\))` - look behind for a digit `OR` end parentes

`(?<!\([\d,]+)` - negative look behind for start parentes followed by one or more  digits `OR` commas

`,` - match a comma `,`

Now simply replace with a dot `.`.

I have made a test case here: [NetRegexBuilder](https://bak-o-soft.dk/RegExp/NetRegexBuilder/LIiXBQ).

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the input chars and generate a new char array according to the condition. 
I don't know about c#, but the Java code should be like the below:

```
    String input = "12,15,22,(46),78,234,1,89,12,(21,99,66),78,65,63,(343,5)";
    char[] outputChars = new char[input.length()];

    int leftBraketCnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if('(' == c) {
            leftBraketCnt++;
        }
        if(')' == c) {
            leftBraketCnt--;
        }

        if(leftBraketCnt == 0 && c == ',') {
            outputChars[i] = '.';
        }else
            outputChars[i] = c;
    }

    String output = new String(outputChars);
    System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take nested parenthesis into account, using .NET u can use a capture group matching [balanced parenthesis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#balancing_group_definition)

In the replacement you can use a callback function checking for the existence of group 1. If it exisis, replace with group 1, else replace with a dot.

```
(\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\))|,
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7bIivw/1)

Only matching a comma when there is a digit to the left or right using lookarounds:

```
(\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\))|(?<=[0-9]),|,(?=[0-9])
```

**Explanation**

- `(\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\))` Capture balanced parenthesis in group 1
  -`|` Or
- `(?<=[0-9]),` Match a comma when there is a digit to the left
- `|` Or
- `,(?=[0-9])` Match a comma when there is a digit to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l8yzF)A/1